# I want to transfer heat from a solar concentrator to be stored in a sand battery , which heat transfer fluid is more viable , cheap and easy to use?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, heat-transfer

I am searching about connecting a solar concentrating system to a sand battery so I need a viable ,cheap and practical heat transfer fluid to distribute and store solar heat into the sand layers up to 600 Celsius degrees without using any mechanical device including fans and pumps.
there are some options like CO<sub>2</sub> , air, molten salt .

My specific question is that which heat transfer fluid under which mechanism can solve my problems?

Comment: Just check out the fluids available and the specific conditions you have - make a list.

Comment: Without knowing your entire situation we can't tell you -- and your question may end up being too long.  Basically, you need to design a strawman system or two, then see how hard they are to knock down.  While you're doing that, be sure to ask what happens with your molten salt system if the salt freezes in the pipes -- how will you restart?

Comment: @TimWescott use a drainback system then.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to beat good old fashioned pressurized water. The attendant technology is fully mature, extremely well-understood, and used all over the world.

Comment: What pressure is needed to keep water liquid at 600 degrees C?

Comment: @SolarMike approximately one bazillion PSI. they guy probably doesn't need to go to 600C- if he really really does he'll need to use something like liquid sodium.